# how to check if property exists in children of the object?

Tags: javascript

if i have an object like `a.b.c.d = "exists"` and i want to check `if (a.b.c.d){..}` is true.

Then how can i do it without getting an error.  if obj `a` doesn't exist. I get an error and program stops. I want program to continue and if obj a or b or c or d don't exist, just it should evaluate to false.

it makes sense if `a` doesn't exit then so doesn't `d`, why does browser give an error here? And how can i fix this i certianly don't want to do this: `if (a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d) {..}`

Comment: The example you gave of what you don't want to do is actually a fairly common practice, though often not necessary to so many levels.

Comment: is there a function that could do this: so i can write `if ( exists(a.b.c.d)) {..}`

Comment: Wrap your if statement in a try...catch block

Comment: FWIW, there are talks about an "existential" operator for ES7 (or later), that could look like `a.?b.?c`, but that's still quite a bit in the future.

Comment: good to know, and i have been thinking of try catch, but i was wondering if there existed a way because seems important to be able to check such stuff

Comment: It's certainly better to check than to use try/catch for this type of work.  Exceptions are meant to be exceptional, not things you can routinely test for.  The dupe question has a couple of good answers.